# Line break not appearing in <DIV> in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

This is my html

```
<div style="width:100%;clear:both;"/>
```

The above empty **div** creates a line break in IE6 & IE7.  In IE8 it is not creating any line breaks.  I do not think the style of this div is the problem.  I am not able to find a post related to this Stackoverflow.  Please clarify or point me to the right post.

EDIT:  Here's the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/spsaravanaselvan/RuvHg/.  I have two textboxes for sample.  In IE7 standard document mode, there is a small space between the textboxes but not in IE8.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you're experiencing, the rest of your code, or a jsFiddle example?

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle and edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
<br/>
```

Is how you would normally create a line-break, closing off a div like that may not be valid as well. 'clear:both' is normally used to make sure a new element falls below floating elements, don't know why you'd use it as new line.